# closing PHP tag before closing while loop

Tags: php, html, database

I was watching a video tutorial on how to create a basic CMS with PHP and database but I'm wondering why the reason to open the `<?php` tag two times.

Can't I just use a single PHP block?

```
<?php
    include("includes/db.php");
    if(isset($_GET['view_page'])){   //open curly brace which will close
    //later..what???
?>
<table width="1000" border="2px" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;background-color:yellow"colspan='6'><h2>All pages here</h2></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Page No.</th>
        <th>Page Title</th>
        <th>Page Content</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php

        $query="SELECT * FROM `pages`";
        $run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
            $p_id   =$row['p_id'];
            $p_title=$row[1];
            $p_desc =substr($row[2],0,100); //on table show 0 to 100 characters long

    ?>
        <td><?php echo $p_id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $p_title; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $p_desc; ?></td>
        <td><a href="delete_page.php?del_page=<?php echo $p_id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }} ?>    //THIS IS REASON OF CONFUSION 
</table>
```

Comment: Sure, you could. The above example makes it easier to output html markup in a literal manner. Doing that in a single block means that you have to `echo` all the markup one by one instead of simply writing it. Things are sometimes easier to read in the above style, though this clearly is limited to template files.

Comment: there is likely to be a html error with the placement of the curly braces. If `$_GET['view_page']` is NOT set you will have an orphaned closing table tag `</table>` - otherwise the use of opening and closing php tags allow regular html content to be rendered without using PHP to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the beauty of php it can be inserted any where in html tag's not in html page . Page must be saved with .php extension to write the php code you have to just write

```
 <?php
 #code
 ?>
```

let say if you want to use while loop but you want some html tags in inside the loop you can easily do this by

```
<?php
while(#condition) {
//inside php tag code
?>
<p> i am html part depend on php codtion</p>
<?php
} //end of while loop
?>
```

there are other ways to

```
<p>
<?php 
echo"hello p tag i am from php ";
?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<?php
    include("includes/db.php");
    if(isset($_GET['view_page'])){   //open curly brace which will close
    //later..what???
?>
        <table width="1000" border="2px" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;background-color:yellow"colspan='6'><h2>All pages here</h2></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>Page No.</th>
                <th>Page Title</th>
                <th>Page Content</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <?php

                    $query="SELECT * FROM `pages`";
                    $run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
                        $p_id   =$row['p_id'];
                        $p_title=$row[1];
                        $p_desc =substr($row[2],0,100); //on table show 0 to 100 characters long


                        echo '<td>'. $p_id; .'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $p_title .'</td>';
                        echo '<td>' .$p_desc .'</td>';
                        echo '<td><a href="delete_page.php?del_page='. $p_id .'">Delete</a></td>';
                    }
                ?>
            </tr>       
        </table>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you have added one addition `}` and additionally you have closed `<tr>` inside the loop that should be done outside... Like this

```
<td><a href="delete_page.php?del_page=<?php echo $p_id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
        <?php } ?>
     </tr>
```

the second `}`  that is of `if(isset(...))` shpuld be closed after the `<table>` has been closed